# Gravity and circular logic

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

My research into gravity indicates that warped spacetime, with time as the major influence, is gravity. It also indicates gravity causes time dilation. Why is this not a circular argument.
It is obvious that gravity is poorly understood with regards to its mechanism even though it is well understood mathematically.why would a mass seek a location where time runs slower?

Comment: You'll really have to give us more detail about what's troubling you.  I don't see any problems in what you wrote so far.  Please edit your question.

Comment: *"My research into gravity indicates that warped spacetime, with time as the major influence, causes gravity."*  - correction:  curved spacetime (geodesic deviation) *is* gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> My research into gravity indicates that warped spacetime, *with time as the major influence*, is gravity

then ask:

> why would a mass seek a location where time runs slower?

But the problem is that few of us will recognise the qualifier *with time as the major influence*, and few of us would describe the motion in a curved spacetime as *mass seeking a location where time runs slower*.

If you look at, for example, the Schwarzschild metric that describes a static black hole it is:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}+r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 $$

It is not obvious that the time term is more important than the radial term or vice verse, so I can't see the justification for your claim *with time as the major influence*.

As for the motion of an object in curved spacetime, this is determined by the curvature coefficients called the Christoffel symbols and calculated using the geodesic equation:

$$ {d^2 x^\mu \over d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} {dx^\alpha \over d\tau} {dx^\beta \over d\tau} = 0 $$

Again, there is no obvious interpretation of this as *mass seeking a location where time runs slower*.

It is true that in the weak field limit time dilation is related to the gravitational potential and the gravitational force is the gradient of the potential, so time dilation and the gravitational force are linked in this way. However you misinterpret this as a causal relationship. Time dilation doesn't cause the gravitational force or vice versa but rather they are both derived from the same underlying physics.

Comment: Warped Time has the greater effect compared to the warping of space

Comment: @RaSullivan: if you're doing a calculation in the weak field limit i.e. in everyday life then it's certainly true that the curvature associated with the time coordinate makes the biggest contribution. After all we see thrown objects move in curves (parabolae) while any spatial curvature in undetectably small. However this is not a general rule and it is not generally true to say GR is mainly time curvature. To say this is to make the (very common :-) mistake of assuming that everyday experience is all there is to physics.

Comment: As we all know gravity is treated as a property of spacetime in GR and of mass in Newtonian physics,  but niether method produces exact solutions so there's more to it. It fascinates me and I'm looking for insight

Comment: @RaSullivan: Newtonian mechanics is a low energy approximation to GR, and it's very common that while low energy approximations are often simpler they can be more mystifying. A good example is non-relativistic quantum mechanics, which is a low energy approximation to quantum field theory. In quantum mechanics the wave-particle duality has mystified generations of physics students but becomes trivial when you learn quantum field theory. So although QFT is (much!) more complicated than quantum mechanics in some ways it is conceptually simpler. The same applies to GR and Newtonian physics.

Comment: @RaSullivan: incidentally, while I'm not sure exactly what you mean by *neither method produces exact solutions*, you should note that right now [the experimental evidence for GR](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377) is very strong. While most of us expect that GR will be modified by quantum effects at very short distances most of us regard it as a good description of physics under all other circumstances.

Comment: As do I. Appreciate your input!

Comment: I wonder how many times you've written the Schwarzschild metric in your PSE career.

Comment: @0celo7: [one hundred and forty](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=schwarzschild+metric+user%3A1325) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Physics is full of theories that to the outsider seem to pose a chicken and egg problem, but there is no issue: both "mass tells space how to curve" and "space tells mass how to more" are axioms of a conceptual structure whose validation is that it's predictions agree with reality. There is no reason to expect one to come "before" the other because they are two aspects of a single thing.

Of course a presentation of the ideas in text or in person has to be structured in a linear fashion and the presenter may choose to expound on either one first, but that has nothing to do with the local foundations.

Again, I'll emphasize this: theories in the physical science don't have to be derived piece by piece because they don't rest on logical deduction for their validity. Their value comes from their ability to predict and explain reality first, and from their beauty and parsimony only afterward.

Comment: This outsider is looking for some insight on a topic which is clearly not understood with regard to mechanism. Why a mass should want to move to a location where time is dialated has a basis in what?

Comment: I appreciate your comments and clearly have not succeeded in posing my question correctly

Comment: You've misunderstood the theory: the following of geodesics is a simple extension of the inertia idea from classical mechanics. In the absence of a unbalanced force that is what objects do. And at this time there is no deeper theory with which to answer a "Why?" question about GR. All we've got is *"Because that is how the world is observed to behave, and this is the most beautiful and parsimonious theory that correctly predicts such behavior."* Which is OK; that is what science is about.

Comment: Why would mass want to relocate to a location of slower time ? What is the motivation?

Comment: I would appreciate your thoughts on the revised question posed by my last comment

Comment: There is not only no motivation there is no such rule. Objects follow geodesics. When they start from local rest those will, indeed, point toward regions of locally slower time, but that is a special case of the general rule that says they follow "straight" lines (for values of straight that are defined by the differential geometry of GR). And there is no motivation for that either. All there is— **all** —is *"Because that is how the world is observed to behave, and this is the most beautiful and parsimonious theory that correctly predicts such behavior."* That is the last word on the subject.

Comment: No. The theory *works*.W hich is the gold standard that overrules any amount of naval gazing and wishful argumentation: things that *work* are more right than things the do not. Every time.

Comment: And this is why mathematics is the clearly superior discipline!